# Cannot send midi note out using NAudio and teVirtualMIDI

Tags: c#, naudio

I am trying to send a Midi Note On message out to DAW software using NAudio, with a virtual port created by teVirtualMIDI.  I am able to see the "device" created by teVirtualMIDI in Ableton Live 10, but have been unsuccessful in receiving any information in Live.  My sound is turned up, and I never see Live's Midi meter move.  The Code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NAudio.Midi;
using TobiasErichsen.teVirtualMIDI;

namespace BDBConsole_1_0
{
    public class BDBMidiClient
    {
        public static ConsoleKeyInfo cKi;
        public static TeVirtualMIDI port;
        static MidiOut midiOut;
        int midiOutIndex;
        //public static List<MidiEvent> noteEvent;

        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            CreateMidiPort();
        }


        public static void CreateMidiPort()
        {
            TeVirtualMIDI.logging(TeVirtualMIDI.TE_VM_LOGGING_MISC | TeVirtualMIDI.TE_VM_LOGGING_RX | TeVirtualMIDI.TE_VM_LOGGING_TX);

            string portName = "BDB Client";
            //port = new TeVirtualMIDI(portName, 65535, TeVirtualMIDI.TE_VM_FLAGS_INSTANTIATE_BOTH);
            port = new TeVirtualMIDI(portName);

            Console.WriteLine("New Midi Port Opened...");
            Console.ReadKey();

            EnumerateMidiOutDevices();

            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SendNextMidiOutMessage)); 
            thread.Start();

            //SendNextMidiOutMessage();
        }


        public static void EnumerateMidiOutDevices() 
        {

            int noOutDevices = MidiOut.NumberOfDevices;
            Console.WriteLine("No. of Midi Out Devices..." + noOutDevices);
            Console.ReadKey();

            string deviceOutOne = MidiOut.DeviceInfo(1).ProductName;
            Console.WriteLine("Device One..." + deviceOutOne);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }


        public static void SendNextMidiOutMessage()
        {
            midiOut = new MidiOut(deviceNo: 0);
            //events = new List<MidiEvent>();
            int channel = 1;
            int note = 64;
            var noteOnEvent = new NoteOnEvent(0, channel, note, 127, 1000);

            try
            {
                //while (true) loop here before
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Send Midi Note...");
                    cKi = Console.ReadKey();

                    midiOut.Send(noteOnEvent.GetAsShortMessage());
                    Console.WriteLine("Note Sent...");
                    cKi = Console.ReadKey();
                } while (cKi.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);

                port.shutdown();
                Console.WriteLine("Midi Port Closed...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("thread aborting: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any Help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't know, but it looks suspicious to me that in `EnumerateMidiOutDevices()` you seem to be interested in device #1, whereas in `SendNextMidiOutMessage()` you seem to work with device #0. Also, what is the hoopla with starting a background thread? There is no point in starting `SendNextMidiOutMessage()` as a background thread if it needs to interact through the console anyway...

Comment: Whoops, `(deviceNo; #)` should be one, and has been for most of my testing.  I opened the thread, as the demo project included with the teVirtualMIDI SDK did so.  I have also tried calling `SendNextMidiOutMessage()` without making a background thread, and also have the same problem.  Thank you for your help though!